# No consigo solucionar un problema con un if

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, if, timer

Estoy realizando un juego en el cual tiene que calcular el tiempo en segundos que se pide por teclado, y cuando supere ese tiempo que se termine el juego. Pero cuando pasa por ese `if`, no calcula el tiempo o es infinito o solo te deja jugar una ronda.
Os dejo el código:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        long tiempoini, tiempofin;
        Instrucciones num;
        boolean seguimos ;
        Instrucciones.pedirTiempoYCantidad();

        do {
            tiempoini = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            num = new Instrucciones();
            long y = tiempoini + num.getTiempoJue();
            tiempofin = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

            if (tiempofin< y) {               
                if(num.getCant()==0){
                  System.out.println("Has acertado las " + num.getCantOperaciones() + " operaciones.Has ganado!!");
                  seguimos=false;
                }else{
                    seguimos=true;
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("LO SIENTO, SE HA ACABADO EL TIEMPO PARA REALIZAR MAS OPERACIONES.");
                seguimos=false;
            }       
        } while (seguimos);
        if (num.getCant() != 0) {
            System.out.println("Lo siento, no ha acertado " + num.getCantOperaciones() + " operaciones.Has  perdido!!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás calculando tiempo de juego?
Seguramente sea cero por eso el if se va siempre al mismo lado.

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente codigo:

```
tiempoini = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
num = new Instrucciones();
long y = tiempoini + num.getTiempoJue();
tiempofin = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

A menos que el constructor de `Instrucciones` o el metodo `getTiempoJue()` tarden un tiempo considerable, `tiempoini` y `tiempofin` tendran el mismo valor.

¿Como estas calculando el tiempo de juego?